# Erro ao fazer relação Many to Many com Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, persistência

Estou tentando fazer uma ligação `Many-to-Many` entre as classes `usuario` e `permissao`, utilizando a documentação do [hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many) como referência . Porém quando tento gerar um arquivo JSON da classe `usuario` o programa entra em loop e gera um arquivo inesperado.

Como evitar isso e fazer com ele limite o arquivo de saída.

Estou utilizando o **Spring Boot 2.0.2**

Abaixo estão as minhas classes:

**Usuario.Class**

```
public class Usuario {
    protected long id;
    protected String nome;
    private String senha;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Permissao> permissao;
}
```

**Permissao.class**

```
public class Permissao{
    protected long id;
    protected String nome;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissao")
    private List<Usuario> usuario;
}
```

**SQL(Os constraints foram retirados para simplificação)**

```
CREATE TABLE usuario
(
  id    INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
  nome  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  senha VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE usuario_permissao
(
  usuario_id   INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  permissao_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE permissao
(
  id   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
)
```

e a **saída em JSON**

```
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","senha":"admin","permissao":
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","usuario":
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","senha":"admin","permissao":
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","usuario":
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","senha":"admin","permissao":
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","usuario":
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","senha":"admin","permissao":
[{"id":1,"nome":"admin","usuario":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral, não é uma boa ideia usar as entidades JPA/Hibernate e transformá-las em Json, ou envolvê-las em qualquer outro tipo de serialização. Como ela pode envolver mapeamentos circulares (como no seu caso), isto pode criar situações como a sua, além de muitos outros problema que vão de desempenho até manutenção.

Para este tipo de problema, é mais flexível e seguro usar algum tipo de classe DTO e transformar elas no Json apropriado. Isto pode ser feito sem muito esforço usando alguma classe utilitária de [mapper](http://modelmapper.org) para transformar de Entidade para DTO.

Exemplo, considere os DTOs:

```
class UsuarioDto {
     private Long id;
     private String nome;
     private List<PermissaoDto> permissao;
}

class PermissaoDto {
     private Long id;
     private String nome;
}
```

E usando algum mapper:

```
UsuarioDto usuarioDto = mapper.map(usuario, UsuarioDto.class);
```

Se os campos tiverem o mesmo nome na entidade e DTO, a conversão é realizada de forma transparente. Este DTO pode ser serializado sem problemas e você tem total controle do que quer exibir (ou não) no Json.